# Appending images to an existing Excel file into a new sheet with Python

Tags: python, pandas, image

I recently started with Python and I am appending the resulting data frame to an existing Excel file.

I want to do the same by appending a figure that I am generating earlier in the code to the same Excel file but on a different sheet.

```
plt.savefig('image.png', dpi = 1200, bbox_inches = 'tight')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl', mode = 'a', if_sheet_exists = 'replace')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet', index = 'False')
writer.close()
```

Is it possible to efficiently add the data frame and image by opening the excel file only once?